# for loop inside always posedge clock

Tags: for-loop, verilog

Sir,
I have some doubts regarding for loop inside the `always` block. Please clarify     me. All iterations have done in single clock cycle?. what will occur when `for` loop inside another `for` loop which is inside `always` block?
Please help me to find mistakes in the following program.Thank You

```
reg [5:0] c;
reg [2:0] m;
reg G[5:0][2:0] = {{1'b1,1'b0,1'b0},{1'b0,1'b1,1'b0},{1'b0,1'b0,1'b1},   {1'b1,1'b1,1'b0},{1'b0,1'b1,1'b1},{1'b1,1'b0,1'b1}};   
integer i;
integer j;
always @(posedge clk1)
begin
   for(i=0;i<6;i=i+1)
        begin
            c[i]=0;
            for(j=2;j>=0;j=j-1)
               begin
                  c[i] <= c[i]^( m[j]&G[2-j][i]);
               end
        end  
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Think of an `always` block as a little bit of software that models a little bit of hardware. The *sensitivity list* is a list of triggers that, when any of them change, the software executes to calculate what the new outputs should be.

For a *combinational* `always` block all the inputs are in the sensitivity list (using the `@(*)` construct), so if any input changes, the outputs of that little bit of hardware may change (pretty much the definition of combinational logic). So, should any of the inputs change, the software executes to calculate what the new outputs from that little bit of combinational logic will be.

For a *sequential* `always` block, only the clock and (if present) asynchronous reset are in the sensitivity list, because no other input directly causes the outputs to change. Therefore, for a sequential block, should the clock (or asynchronous reset) change, then the software executes to calculate what the new outputs of that little bit of sequential logic will be.

So, in your case, you have a sequential `always` block *without* an asynchronous reset. It is a little bit of software which models a little bit of sequential logic. The outputs of this sequential logic will only change if the clock changes (if there is a rising edge on `clk1`). So, if there is a rising edge on `clk1`, the code inside the `always` block starts executing in order to calculate what the new values of the array `c` will be (the outputs of your sequential logic, because that is the *variable* assigned in this particular `always` block). The fact that there happen to be loops in this particular code doesn't matter. If there is a rising edge on `clk1` then the loops will execute completely (without waiting for any more rising edges on `clk1`) in order to calculate what the new values of `c` will be.